# Routing ABCs - Packet goes up, must come down

Tags: networking, routing

Can anyone give me a summary of routing technologies?  A packet is kicked into the air, reaches an apex, and comes down to earth at some destination.  Kicking is pretty simple.  The packet just follows default gateways until it reaches a point where default gateways aren't good enough.

Where is the apex exactly?  And what takes over for static routing?  I'm guessing this usually occurs at the edge of the local business unit (commercial, university, ISP).  Does the edge compare well to IANA assignments?  I suspect BGP fits in here somewhere.  Where though? The exact edge of the network?  How does OPSF fit in?  (Are there any very common protocols besides BGP and OPSF?)

And finally, if a big switch is rebooted, and some of these heavier dynamic routing tables get axed, is the local lan looking at downtime?

Lotsa questions.  Really, just a simplified explanation will do.  This tends to get bogged down in Cisco documentation and it's pretty unapproachable for a simple programmer like me.  TIA.

Answer (score 3):

> Can anyone give me a summary of routing technologies?

Anything with more than one NIC can be a router.  It can be a PC running Linux or a dedicated device, typically a dedicated device will route fastest and most efficiently.

> Where is the apex exactly?

A router will either forward a packet A) directly to its final destination IP if the destination is on the same subnet, or B) to a gateway IP that the router is told that the packet's subnet can be reached through, according to its "Forwarding Information Base."  There are many ways to propagate a FIB, i.e. tell a router what gateway IPs can be used to reach what subnets.

A campus environment may use OSPF and other routing/gateway protocols that tell routers what the next hops are.  Tier-1 ISPs use BGP to trade information about routes between each other.  The "global BGP" table is pretty much "the apex" you are talking about.

> And what takes over for static routing?

Static routes are just a name for "manually programmed routes", so the router is just doing what you tell it.  If you tell a router that a specific subnet is behind a specific interface, it will send traffic going to that subnet out of that interface, assuming less specific rules don't apply.  You can change the order FIB rules are applied with a value called the *metric*.

> And finally, if a big switch is rebooted, and some of these heavier dynamic routing tables get axed, is the local lan looking at downtime?

One task of network engineers is to ensure there are redundant paths to destinations.  Assuming they did their job properly.  With things like OSPF, the routers are aware of multiple paths to a destination, and pick the "lowest cost" route, but failover to another route if a router stops responding.  There are "hello" and "heartbeat" parts of the protocols that let routers find out about each other and keep the routers informed about each others state.  The same can be done with BGP.

If you only have 1 path out of your LAN, as is the case with a typical residential cable-modem connection, you are down if the ISP goes down.  In a campus or corporate network you would set up redundancy with multiple ISPs, or multiple internal routers.

Comment: I would say an apex candidate are those networks that do not have any default routes on their backbone.  These networks are where packets to un-routed networks go to die.